# Cannot connect AWS lambda to mysql database

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services

Hi I cant seem to connect my sql db to my lambda function. The following is the code I tried to use. I have already added a layer for my package.json. I linked my lambda function to amazon lex but it threw out this error 'An error has occurred: Invalid Lambda Response: Received error response from Lambda: Unhandled' when I tried to print ${connection.state}. I also added the necessary lambda permissions.

Would appreciate the help thanks!

```
function dispatch(intentRequest, callback) {
 const sessionAttributes = intentRequest.sessionAttributes;
 const slots = intentRequest.currentIntent.slots;

 const mysql = require("mysql");

 var connection = mysql.createConnection({
 host     : 'xxx',
 user     : 'admin',
 password : 'xxx',
 database : 'xxx',
 port : 3306
});

exports.handler = (event, context) => {
 connection.connect(function(err) {
   if (err) context.fail();
   else context.succeed('Success');
 });
};

 callback(close(sessionAttributes, 'Fulfilled',
 {'contentType': 'PlainText', 'content': `Thank you ${connection.state}`}));
}
// Route the incoming request based on intent.
// The JSON body of the request is provided in the event slot.
exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
 try {
     dispatch(event,
         (response) => {
             callback(null, response);
         });
 } catch (err) {
     callback(err);
 }
}
```

Comment: There’s no handler in your code. Probably the error is in the handler (response format? another exception?), but we can’t see it. Can you post the handler too?

Comment: exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
    connection.query('show tables', function (error, results, fields) {
        if (error) {
            throw error;
        } else {
            console.log(results);
            callback(error, results);
        }
    });
};

Comment: Hi, i tried this but the ${connection.status} printed as disconnected.

Comment: You’re querying connection while not connected. Try to await the connect operation in your handler, and only after connection has been established try to fire a query

Comment: Hey when i used this, the connection.status is similar as well. 
var con = mysql.createConnection({
  host: "localhost",
  user: "yourusername",
  password: "yourpassword"
});

exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => con.connect(function(err) {
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log("Connected!");
});

Comment: Something’s reported into the cloudwatch logs? If you can see the “Connected!” string, you just have to call you just have to call the callback with a response that Lex could handle.

Comment: ```exports.handler = async (event, context) => {
 await connection.connect(function(err) {
   if (err) context.fail();
   else context.succeed('Success');
 });

callback(close(sessionAttributes, 'Fulfilled',
 {'contentType': 'PlainText', 'content': `Thank you ${connection.state}`}));
};```

Comment: I tried the above but it shows a null response from lambda.

Comment: Shows error in cloudwatch logs

Comment: Hi I have edited the code above to make it clearer on what I did.